# RegExp lookbehind assertion alternative

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Given the string below, how would you split this into an array containing only the double quoted strings (ignoring nested quoted strings) without using a lookbehind assertion?

source string: `1|2|3|"A"|"B|C"|"\"D\"|\"E\""`

target array:

```
[
  '"A"',
  '"B|C"',
  '"\"D\"|\"E\""'
]
```

Basically, I'm trying to find an alternative to `/(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"/g` since Firefox currently doesn't support lookbehinds. The solution doesn't have to use regular expressions, but it should be reasonably efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find all the quoted text `/"[^"\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^"\\]*)*"/g`
Don't need split for this.

https://regex101.com/r/r5SJsR/1

Formatted

```
 "
 [^"\\]*                       # Double quoted text
 (?: \\ [\S\s] [^"\\]* )*
 "
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the simple regex `/"[^\\"]+"|"\S*"/g`.

- The first two sets (`"A"'` and `"B|C"`) are covered by `"[^\\"]+"` - anything that is not a backslash or a quotation mark wrapped inside a set of quotation marks
- A pipe (`|`) separates the two conditionals
- The third set (`"\"D\"|\"E\""`) is simply covered by `"\S*"` - anything non-whitespace wrapped inside a set of quotation marks

This returns the same results as your initial regex, has no lookbehinds and can be seen working on **[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/VOPZDm/1/)**.

Comment: This works for the one example given in the question, but it stops working once you reorder the pipe-separated string, e.g.: `1|2|3|"A"|"\"D\"|\"E\""|"B|C"`

Comment: Matches `"hello\\"world"`